# Generalization of affine algebraic sets.

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have the following definitions:

**Quasi-projective algebraic set:** a subset of $\mathbb P^n$ which is a closed set of an open set in $\mathbb P^n$.

**Affine quasi-projective algebraic set:** a quasi-projective algebraic set which is isomorphic to an affine closed set.

I'm a really beginner and my question is quite simple. I would like to know which definition (maybe both) is a generalization of the concept of affine algebraic set.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

"Quasi-projective algebraic set" is obviously a generalization of "affine quasi-projective algebraic set", and the latter is a generalization of "affine algebraic set" (can you see why?). So, in short, the answer is: both.

Comment: I'm trying to prove it, do you have any hint? thanks for your help.

Comment: @user42912 Hint: $\mathbf A^n$ is an open subset of $\mathbf P^n$.